# Is it possible to install Rust on Linux without admin privileges?

Tags: linux, rust

version: 1.0.0 beta 5

I have gotten as as far as running the install.sh script with the argument "--prefix=$HOME/local" (installing to my home directory)

and this works fine, but ldconfig (part of the install.sh process) fails because of lack of root privileges, and then rustc is unable to find the libraries

```
rustc: error while loading shared libraries: librustc_driver-4e7c5e5c.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you specify a different prefix, you need to set the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable. This is a colon-separated list (like `PATH`) which is typically not set. You’ll want something like this in your shell config:

```bash
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:~/local/lib"
```

Comment: And for good measure, although this question is about Linux, OS X users can use `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` to the same end.

Comment: On my system (Debian Jessie) this doesn't work, I have to use the path up to the `lib` component, i.e. `"$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:~/local/lib"`.